# Limit length of line from session close ot next session close using bar_time

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to create a line from the London session close that extends until the next london session close and ends. How can I do this using bar_time? The whole bar_time thing really confuses me. Need this to work on all timeframes(automatically) and start and end at the exact right times. Any ideas?

`line.new(time, array.max(londonSessionHighPrice), time + 60, array.max(londonSessionHighPrice), xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=londonSessionLineColor, width=1)`

I have searched for examples of this type of things, but can't find any that fit my needs.